# How to find out the size of a dynamic Eigen vector in bytes?

Tags: c++, size, eigen, sizeof, eigen3

I'm going to calculate the size of the vector. If I write this code:

```cpp
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, 1, Eigen::ColMajor> staticVector;
    std::cout << "sizeInBytes: " << sizeof (staticVector) << std::endl;
```

the output is:

```cpp
sizeInBytes: 24
```

But if I write:

```cpp
    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::ColMajor> dynamicVector;
    dynamicVector.resize(6);
    std::cout << "sizeInBytes: " << sizeof (dynamicVector) << std::endl;
```

the output is:

```cpp
sizeInBytes: 16
```

Okay, the **sizeof (vector)** doesn't show the real size of the dynamic vector. What should I use? I would try **sizeof (float) * vector.size()** or **sizeof (float) * vector.size() + sizeof (vector)**, but not sure if this is the correct option. So what do I need?

Comment: sizeof is a compile-time operator. You cannot get real size with it. If you know the size (number of elements) in the vector, why can't you get the size ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This question is actually part of a more complex one that I will ask on the stackoverflow a little later. The real reason for this situation is that I am trying to transfer a dynamic vector to the GPU using Cuda. And getting some errors in cudaMemcpy, most likely related to calculating the size of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Eigen::Matrix`'s array is all in the stack, then `sizeof` should return the right value. This would be great for small Matrices, but could become dangerous for largest, as it could cause stack overflow.

If data are stored in the heap then you need to make a method that adds stack and heap memory and returns it. This would be an possible example:

```
template<class T, size_t ROWS, size_t COLS, Eigen::SomeEnumType>
class Matrix {
    // ...
  private:
    std::array<std::array<T, COLS>, ROWS> *data;

  public:
    Matrix() { data = new std::array<std::array<T, COLS>, ROWS>(); }

    // Assumes all dynamically allocated memory is the data.
    size_t sizeInBytes() const { return sizeof(T) * ROWS * COLS + sizeof(*this); }
};
```

About the concern in the comment:

> I am trying to transfer a dynamic vector to the GPU using Cuda

I've worked very little with CUDA so I might be wrong, but IIRC the only way to put things to the GPU with with a `memcpy`-like operation. This would be very hard to impossible for vectors, which contain both stack and heap data far from each other. The best way would be to allocate all data inside the object (so it's contiguous in memory), and then if you're scared of stack overflow simply allocate the whole object on the heap:

```
template<class T, size_t ROWS, size_t COLS, Eigen::SomeEnumType>
class Matrix {
    // ...

    std::array<std::array<T, COLS>, ROWS> data;
}; 

int main() {
  auto *mat = new Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, 1, Eigen::ColMajor>(...);
  void *GPU_mat = malloc_GPU(sizeof(*mat));
  memcpy_to_GPU(GPU_mat, mat, sizeof(*mat));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. If I understood your answer correctly, my guess with "sizeof (float) * vector.size() + sizeof (vector)" was correct. I was not sure if the *data is the only part of the object stored on the heap. And thanks for the advice to allocate the whole object on the heap. I don't think it will save me now, but it can definitely help later.

Comment: Yes you were correct. That being said even by getting the size of a vector you still won't be able to move it because it is not contiguous. And even if it was, the address `data` is pointing at would be invalidated.Also vector is implementation dependent, so it's not necessarily structured this way (thought it should very likely be).